# Django Twilio API Custom Body Form

Tags: python, django, sms, twilio

Using the code below, what is the best way to create a custom "body" for sending an SMS message using the Twilio API?

```
to = '+11111111111'
client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
                response = client.messages.create(
                 body='Hello, testing Twilio in Django', 
                 to=to, from_=settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by custom "body"? Like a different message?

Comment: Yes, a form to type and send the message.

Comment: What message do you want to send? Does this code not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, yes this code works, but it is just had coding the message. I was just trying to see if there was a simple solution to create a form to send your own message using a form. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the form? Is it a Google Form?

Comment: I haven't created it yet. I was kind of struggling with the logic and using this view. I assume I would need a message model and form.